# Error when starting MySQL from XAMPP InnoDB

Tags: mariadb

Yesterday MySQL was working fine in XAMPP, but today is giving error. I put zlib1.dll in my Sytem32 folder, I don't know if it is the error reason.
My databases are 200 mb in size.
I have already changed de port, but the error still
.

XAMPP

```
10:45:11  [mysql]   Attempting to start MySQL app...
10:45:11  [mysql]   Status change detected: running
10:45:15  [mysql]   Status change detected: stopped
10:45:15  [mysql]   Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
10:45:15  [mysql]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
10:45:15  [mysql]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
10:45:15  [mysql]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
10:45:15  [mysql]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
10:45:15  [mysql]   If you need more help, copy and post this
10:45:15  [mysql]   entire log window on the forums
```

mysql_error.log

```
InnoDB: using atomic writes.
2019-12-06 10:45:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2019-12-06 10:45:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2019-12-06 10:45:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2019-12-06 10:45:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2019-12-06 10:45:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2019-12-06 10:45:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2019-12-06 10:45:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2019-12-06 10:45:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2019-12-06 10:45:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2019-12-06 10:45:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2019-12-06 10:45:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2019-12-06 10:45:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2019-12-06 10:45:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.8 started; log sequence number 355449150; transaction id 22374
2019-12-06 10:45:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2019-12-06 10:45:11 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2019-12-06 10:45:11 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2019-12-06 10:45:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 191206 10:45:11
```

my.ini

```
[client]
port=3306
socket="C:/xampp/mysql/mysql.sock"
default-character-set=utf8mb4

[mysqld]
port=3306
socket="C:/xampp/mysql/mysql.sock"
basedir="C:/xampp/mysql"
tmpdir="C:/xampp/tmp"
datadir="C:/xampp/mysql/data"
pid_file="mysql.pid"
key_buffer=16M
max_allowed_packet=1M
sort_buffer_size=512K
net_buffer_length=8K
read_buffer_size=256K
read_rnd_buffer_size=512K
myisam_sort_buffer_size=8M
log_error="mysql_error.log"
plugin_dir="C:/xampp/mysql/lib/plugin/"
server-id   =1
innodb_data_home_dir="C:/xampp/mysql/data"
innodb_data_file_path=ibdata1:10M:autoextend
innodb_log_group_home_dir="C:/xampp/mysql/data"
innodb_buffer_pool_size=16M
innodb_log_file_size=5M
innodb_log_buffer_size=8M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1
innodb_lock_wait_timeout=50
sql_mode=NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
log_bin_trust_function_creators=1
character-set-server=utf8mb4
collation-server=utf8mb4_general_ci

[mysqldump]
max_allowed_packet=16M

[mysql]

[isamchk]
key_buffer=20M
sort_buffer_size=20M
read_buffer=2M
write_buffer=2M

[myisamchk]
key_buffer=20M
sort_buffer_size=20M
read_buffer=2M
write_buffer=2M

[mysqlhotcopy]
```

MariaDB Error:
`Slave I/O: Fatal error: Invalid (empty) username when attempting to connect to the master server. Connection attempt terminated. Internal MariaDB error code: 1593`

Comment: mysql doesn't show any errors, so check the windows event viewer for errors.

Comment: How do I check?

Comment: enter event in windows search it or https://www.isunshare.com/windows-10/6-ways-to-open-event-viewer-in-windows-10.html

Comment: I found a MariaDB Error

Comment: if the user table was damaged, it shut also show in the logs, try to repair all tables or restore from a recent backup

Comment: _I found a MariaDB Error_ Thats because you are using mariaDB and NOT using MySQL

Comment: Do you mean to be trying to use REPLICATION?  If not remove the server-id line in your configuration.

Comment: Error seems you are trying to connect without user and with failed attempt mariadb/mysql blocks all incoming TCP connections. First Please check if service is running or not and share how you are connecting this instance .

Answer (score 3):

Here are the steps I followed that helped me solve the problem.

1. Open xampp -> htdocs -> MySQL -> data
2. Delete all the files (**Don't touch any of the folders**) except for
   the following files: aria_log.00000001, aria_log_control,
   ib_buffer_pool, ib_logfile0, ib_logfile1, ibdata1, ibtmp1,
   multi-master.info, my.ini, mysql.pid, mysql_error.

Comment: this one actually helped, I tried a couple other advices but none of the worked - thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps you too:

1. Open your xampp control panel to stop Apache & MySQL
2. Now select explorer (from control panel) OR alternatively, open your xampp folder if you know its installation path
3. Open mysql folder and keep a copy of your data folder
4. Lastly, copy all the files (except "ibdata1") from backup folder and replace them in the original data folder

Restart xampp and start using its services :)

Answer (score 0):

innodb_log_file_size should NEVER be smaller than innodb_log_buffer_size.

Consider changing your my.ini [mysqld] section for

```
innodb_log_file_size=100M
```

Will require stop/start or restart after saving your my.ini